# What does multiple key combinations over a paragraph in the manual mean? That they're synonyms?

Tags: neovim, original-vim

Searching for `i(`, and got a paragraph with these combinations above: `v_i)`, `i)`, `i(`, `vib`, `v_ib`, `v_i(`, and `ib`.

Are all these synonyms?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are *tag* synonyms. That is, any of them can be used to reach the same point whether by  way of `:help {tagname}`, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> when the cursor is over text of the form `*{tagname}*` or any of the handful of other ways you can navigate tags.

So, for example, `:h v_i)` and `:h i(` will both take you to the same place. Note that the particular entry chosen as an example has a much higher number of tags than usual since it's about a text object with three synonyms of its own and each of those can be used in both Normal and Visual modes. How does being able to use them in Normal and Visual modes have any bearing on the number of associated tags? Glad you asked...

Highly recommended reading: [`:h help-summary`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_02.txt.html#help-summary). The prefixes of many tags have particular meanings. For example `v_` means a Visual mode command. You'll find definitions for the prefixes in that section. This is very useful when searching for help on a topic. Actually, do yourself a favor and back up about a page and start reading at the beginning of the section (*02.8 Finding help*). Good stuff.